# Stuck and IF or ELSE

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The problem is that is does not show the idade, its actually to give a answer depends of what do you put into the input, i.e. the function only recognize the first condition.

I have tried debugging the code, but I'm getting:

> No debug adapter, can not send ‘evaluate’

```js
var idade = document.querySelector('input#nmd')
var n1 = Number(idade.value)
var res = document.getElementById('res')

function clicar() {
  if (n1 < 16) {
    res.innerHTML = ('Nao vota')
  }
  if (n1 < 18) {
    res.innerHTML = ('Voto opcional')
  } else if (n1 > 18) {
    res.innerHTML = ('Voto obrigado')
  }
}
```

```html
<h1><strong></strong>Verificador de multas</strong>
</h1>
<input type="number" name="nmd" id="nmd" value="Digite">
<input type="button" value="ir" id="ir" onclick="clicar()">
<div id="res">
  <h2>Resultado...</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `var n1 = Number(idade.value)` is executed just **once** - at the very beginning. Way before you enter anything. Move it into the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored the function a bit. I don't know what value you use to test, but the first IF statement will be overruled by the second one for every value < 18. I think that is your problem.

You can test this script online at https://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html

```
function clicar(n1) {

    if (n1 < 16) {res = 'Nao vota'} 

    if (n1 < 18) {res = 'Voto opcional'} 
    else 
        if (n1 > 18) {res = 'Voto obrigado'}
    return res
}

alert(clicar(10) + '|' + clicar(17) + '|' + clicar(44));
```

What you can do is exit the function (use return) as soon as you have your answer. Also, don't forget to include `n1 >= 18` instead of `n1 > 18`, else the number 18 will fail.

```
function clicar(n1) {
    if (n1 < 16) {return 'Nao vota'} 

    if (n1 < 18) {return 'Voto opcional'} 

    if (n1 >= 18) {return 'Voto obrigado'}

}

alert(clicar(10) + '|' + clicar(17) + '|' + clicar(44));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the input value only the first time that the script tag is read.

Or, in other word: You're invoking the funcion `clicar` without reading the actual input value.

Below a working example.

```js
function clicar() {
    var idade = document.querySelector('input#nmd')
    var n1 = Number(idade.value)
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    if (n1 < 16) {
        res.innerHTML = ('Nao vota')
    } else if (n1 < 18) {
        res.innerHTML = ('Voto opcional')
    } else if (n1 > 18) {
        res.innerHTML = ('Voto obrigado')
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1><strong></strong>Verificador de multas</strong></h1>
<input type="number" name="nmd" id="nmd" value="Digite">
<input type="button" value="ir" id="ir" onclick="clicar()">
<div id="res">
    <h2>Resultado...</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: So just to know my wrong wasn't about the necessary the function but the else or if actually?

Comment: The main problem was that `document.querySelector('input#nmd')` and `document.getElementById('res')` were outside your function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function clicar() { 
    var idade = document.querySelector('input#nmd');
    var res = document.getElementById('res');
      var n1 = Number(idade.value);
      if (n1 < 16) { 
        res.innerHTML = ('Nao vota') 
      } 
      if (n1 < 18) { 
        res.innerHTML = ('Voto opcional') 
      } else if (n1 > 18) { 
        res.innerHTML = ('Voto obrigado') 
      } 
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
          <h1><strong>Verificador de multas</strong></h1>
          <input type="number" name="nmd" id="nmd" value="Digite">
          <input type="button" value="ir" id="ir" onClick="clicar()">
          <div id="res">
            <h2>Resultado...</h2>
          </div>
</body>
```